# Retrieve user in fixtures class

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle, fixtures

I have to test my app so I want to use the fixtures of doctrine to insert data in database . I want to create a new entry of an entity (a blog post for example) that has a `ManyToOne` relationship with a user entity (fosuser). So, I have to retrieve first user to set as blog post author. The problem is when I run command:

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

I get the following error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to BluEstuary\PostBundle\Model\Post::setOwner() 
must be an instance of BluEstuary\UserBundle\Model\User, null given, called in /Users/bface007/workspace/BluEstuary/esgis_gabon/src/ESGISGabon/PostBundle/DataFixtures/ORM/Posts.php on line 53 and defined in /Users/bface007/workspace/BluEstuary/esgis_gabon/src/BluEstuary/PostBundle/Model/Post.php on line 296`
```

I can retrieve users in non fixtures classes, but it always give null value when I try in fixtures one. Can somebody help me ?

This is my fixtures class:

```
class Posts implements FixtureInterface, ContainerAwareInterface{
    public function load(Objectmanager $manager){
        $blogposts = array(
            array(
                "title" => "This is test 1",
                "content" => "I am a cool example"
            ),
            array(
                "title" => "This is test 2",
                "content" => "I am a cool example"
            )
        );

        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $user = $userManager->findUserBy(array("id" => 3));

        foreach($posts as $i => $post){
            $new_posts[$i] = new BlogPost();
            $new_posts[$i]->setPostTitle($post["title"])
                        ->setPostContent($post["content"]);

            $new_posts[$i]->setAuthor($user);

            $manager->persist($new_posts[$i]);
        }

        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should first create user, because of empty database.

Comment: You are so right. I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use :

```
php app/console doctrine:fixtures:load --append
```

... so it doesn't empty your database beforehand

(Source : https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineFixturesBundle/index.html)

Comment: malcolm and you are so right. I didn't think of that.

Comment: This helped me to understand why $repository->find(1) didn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Right way to load the right data into the fixture is using the references.
Let's say you have an Author fixture:

```
AuthorFixture extends AbstractFixture implements OrderedFixtureInterface {
public function load(ObjectManager $om)
{
   $author = new Author("name", "surname"..);
   $this->setReference("author_1", $author);

   $om->persist($author);
   $om->flush();
}

/**
 * Get the order of this fixture
 * NOTE: the author comes before the Posts
 * @return integer
 */
public function getOrder()
{
    return 1;
}
```

}

Then in your post fixture:

```
new_posts[$i] = new BlogPost();
new_posts[$i]->setAuthor($this->getReference("author_1");

..

/**
 * Get the order of this fixture
 * Note: the post comes after the author
 * @return integer
 */
public function getOrder()
{
    return 2;
}
```

Comment: Yessss! It's absolutely the right way. Thanks erlangb